# is it possible to pass FB token between webview and outside webview controllers

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I am trying to login with FB in webview controller.

After user login in in webview then pass  `the login token` out to the outside controllers

Then store the token into persistant storage.

Therefore, the user only needs to `sign in (once)`.

The reason why I'm doing this way is that

- I'm not able to build the native app view, it a big task for me.
- Familiar with web side but not familiar with  app side.
- Still need some native app function for notifying user.

Please forgive my poor english and little knowledge on app

[image]
[image]